# Ace Of Spades Right After An Ace and Two of Clubs Right After An Ace

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

I came across this question

> A Deck of 52 playing cards is shuffled and the cards are turned up and
> kept on the table. What is the probability that ace of spades comes right after an ace and 2 of
> clubs comes right after an ace?

I tried the following approach:

1. Sample space consists of $52!$ orderings of the cards.
2. Let an event A be all the orderings such that ace of spades is right next to an ace and two of clubs is right next to an ace.

lets denote the set of events described below as $B$. We visualize the 3 aces and denote their positions as $i, j, k (1 \leq i, j, k \leq 52)$
We can choose 3 slots in ${51\choose 3}$ ways (51 because we should not choose the $52^{nd}$ position as we need slots that have an empty slot right next to it. We can permute the 3 aces in these 3 slots in $3!$ ways. Out of these 3 slots, we can choose any 2 slots(for ace of spades and two of clubs) in ${3\choose 2} \cdot 2!(=P(3, 2))$. And the remaining 47 cards can be arranged in $47!$ ways.

Therefore, $$|B| = {51\choose 3} \cdot P(3, 2) \cdot 3! \cdot 47!$$

lets denote the set of events described below as $C$. We visualize the 3 aces with one ace in
the $52^{nd}$ position. We can choose the remaining 2 slots in ${51\choose 2}$ ways. We can permute the 3 aces in these 3 slots in $3!$ ways. Out of these 2 slots, we can choose any 2 slots(for ace of spades and two of clubs) in $P(2, 2)$ ways.  And the remaining 47 cards can be arranged in $47!$ ways.
Therefore. $$|C| = {51\choose 2} \cdot P(2, 2) \cdot 3! \cdot 47!$$

Lets denote the set of events described below as $D$. We can choose from 50 positions for the 3 aces( we cannot choose the 51 and 52 positions because we need 2 empty slots right next to the ace), that is ${50 \choose 3}$ ways. The pair (ace of spades, 2 of clubs) can sit right next to either of these 3 slots in 3 ways. The remaining 47 cards can be arranged in $47!$ ways.
Therefore, $$|D| = {50 \choose 3} \cdot 3! \cdot 3 \cdot 47!$$

$B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive. Also, $|A| = |B| + |C| + |D|$.
Therefore $$P(A) = {\dfrac{{51\choose 3} \cdot P(3, 2) \cdot 3! \cdot 47! + {51\choose 2} \cdot 3! \cdot P(2, 2) \cdot 47! + {50 \choose 3} \cdot 3! \cdot 3 \cdot 47!} {52!}} \approx 0.002404$$

Is my approach correct? If it is, is there a simpler approach? If not, please guide me to the correct approach via hints/solution. Thank you!
**Note**
The problem statement previous to this edit was

> A Deck of 52 playing cards is shuffled and the cards are turned up and
> kept on the table. What is the probability that ace of spades and 2 of
> clubs come right after an ace?

The problem statement turned out to allow for multiple interpretations and @Math Lover's solution is a very elegant one for one of them. I am sorry for the inconvenience caused and will be careful to check that the problem statement is unambiguous before posting it.

Comment: Sadly, math problems are often posed in books or on the internet, with significant ambiguities, for the sake of brevity.  Consider "What is the probability that ace of spades and 2 of clubs are adjacent to an ace?"  It is unclear to me what this signifies.  What happens if the 2 of clubs is adjacent to the Ace of spades, and to no other Ace?  What does adjacent mean?  Are the three cases where the 2 of clubs and Ace of spades are adjacent to each other, or separated by one card from each other, or separated by more than one card from each other, to be considered separately?

Comment: I don't think your calculation accounts for the possibility that two aces are adjacent to each other.

Comment: Re **my** previous comment, if it is required that the 2 of clubs and Ace of spades are each *adjacent* to one of the **other** 3 Aces, is it **required** or **not required** that the **same other Ace** be adjacent to **both** the 2 of Clubs and the Ace of Spades?

Comment: @user2661923 apologies for the ambiguity in the statement. I have revised the problem statement now.

Comment: @RobertShore oops, i just missed the case! Thanks for pointing it out. I have revised the approach now. Is the approach correct now? Am i undercounting or overcounting? Thanks!

Comment: With respect to my comments, the ambiguities are not resolved by "Let an event A be all the orderings such that ace of spades and two of clubs are adjacent to an ace."  I would prefer to not have to **reverse-engineer** your intention by delving into your analysis.  It would be *nice* if you could elaborate your interpretation of the problem **up front** so that it is **impossible** for anyone to be uncertain what you (or the problem) intends.

Comment: The answer of Math Lover is certainly **one** plausible interpretation of your query.  Also, if you accept his interpretation, his math is certainly accurate (and elegant).  **However**, it is **still** unclear (at least to me) whether his interpretation represents the intent of the problem composer.  There are certainly other, equally plausible interpretations.

Comment: @user2661923 yes I understand the point. I answered based on my interpretation.

Comment: @MathLover I flagged you only because, since my comment reflected on your answer, you deserved to be notified.  However, the point of my comment is to attempt to **prod** the OP into making the effort to select a specific interpretation, either yours or some other interpretation, and then **edit his query** so that the start of his query makes it **crystal clear** what **his** interpretation is.  He has not **yet** provided the desired clarification.

Comment: @user2661923 I understand that the problem statement is still not clear.Sincere apologies for that. The solution by math lover is indeed elegant and a perfectly fine interpretation of the problem. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. I will rephrase the problem statement.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I interpret it -

Question says ace of spades and $2$ of clubs come *right* after an ace. Number of arrangements where that happens is $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 50!$

Explanation: We need to consider $\{A \ \textbf{A} \ 2 \}$ as one combined card - that is arrangements of $50$ cards. Now the first ace can be any of the $3$ non-spade ace. Also, $2$ of club and ace of spade can swap places as question does not state their internal order.

So the probability should be $ \displaystyle \frac{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 50!}{52!}$

Comment: See my last comment, following the original query.